# Google Analytics page view tracking

Tags: google-analytics, shiny, pageviews

I am using a shiny dashboard with about 20 pages and recently implemented Google Analytics to track page views. The number of pageviews in GA seems to be the same for all pages. I think that once the home page is hit, all other pages are getting hit as well.

I need help to solve this problem. My GA.js script contains the auto script generated while creating an account with GA and this script.

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {'title': 'Shiny Dashboard','page': '/#shiny-tab-dashboard'});
```

I have generated similar lines for all the pages with different 'title' and 'page'. Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

Google analytics does not record hash parameters by default so you would have to a
change your tracking code
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#allowAnchor
Below are the changes required

Replace 
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');

with
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', {'cookieDomain':'auto','allowAnchor': false});

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried out your way but I am still not able to resolve it. I am still getting multiple hits on all pages once the index page is hit. Any other way to get it done??

Comment: my apologies dear, it would be ga('create','UA-XXXX-Y', {'cookieDomain':'auto','allowAnchor':true}); this will surely work for you :)

Comment: Thanks once again, I implemented your correction but the problem still remains. Any further advice?

Comment: has the anchor tags started showing up in all pages? would you please share your site url.

Comment: I am sorry, but I cannot share my site url. I can tell you this though. The whole site has a single url with different options on the side. When the options are clicked, the main url remains the same throughout. It does not change at all. Only the anchor tags displayed at the left bottom of the page changes.